How to send a date range of a financial year within date_histogram using calendar_interval in ElasticSeach 8
So i have some huge data of some years and i am trying to create transforms in elastic search to aggregate data for each financial year. What calender_interval should be send for it? or we can also use offset. But long offsets over calender_interval don't work.
i have tried sending offset `
 "date_histogram": {
        "field":     "date",
        "calendar_interval":  "1y",
        "offset":    "+90d"
      }

`
but for feb we can have a leap year so there can be 90 or 91 days.
